# How to add a ... when cutting text only if its length is equal to the number of letters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe, truncate

When I cut the text, I want to add "..." if its length is exactly 14 letters, if less, then cut without adding "...". How to implement ?

```js
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'truncate'
})

export class TruncatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, limit = 14, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {
        if (completeWords) {
            limit = value.substr(0, limit).lastIndexOf(' ');
        }
            return `${value.substr(0, limit)}${ellipsis}`;
    }
}
```

```html
<p>{{pic.title | truncate}}</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    transform(value: string, limit = 14, completeWords = false, ellipsis = '...') {
    if (completeWords === true && value.length > limit) {
       return value.substring(0, limit).concat(ellipsis);
    }
    return value; // basiclly do nothing.
}
```

then

```
<p>{{pic.title | truncate:'15':true}}</p>
```